# c++ Why is my date parsing not threadsafe?

Tags: c++, boost, thread-safety, gcc4, date-parsing

```
boost::posix_time::ptime parseDate(const std::string& format, const std::string& localDate)
{
    std::istringstream is(localDate);
    is.imbue(std::locale(is.getloc(), new boost::local_time::local_time_input_facet(format.c_str())));
    boost::posix_time::ptime pt;
    is >> pt;

    if (pt == boost::posix_time::ptime())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Parse error");
    }

    return pt;
}
```

This function should take a date and a format string and `return boost::posix_time::ptime`.

E.g.: `2012:06:14 02:50:58` and `%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S`.

However if I call it in a multithreaded program, sometimes the exception is thrown, although `format` and `localDate` are correct and parseable (I use the same date for every call).
I found something about `std::stringstream`/`std::locale` thread issues but nothing up-to-date (I am using gcc 4.6.3 64bit).

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/29301/#msg160008) someone has the same problem:

> Testing over the last few days using Valgrind/drd, I have found many parts of my code that cause problems. For example, when calling some boost date time conversion functions, I hit std::locale(), which is not threadsafe.

Updated code that gives no problems:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime parseDate(const std::string& format, const std::string& localDate)
{
    std::istringstream is(localDate);
    auto* facet = new boost::local_time::local_time_input_facet(format.c_str());

    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(globalLocaleMutex);
        is.imbue(std::locale(is.getloc(), facet));
    }

    boost::posix_time::ptime pt;
    is >> pt;

    if (pt == boost::posix_time::ptime())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Parse error");
    }

    return pt;
}
```

But still: Why?

Comment: `throw std::runtime_error("Parse error");`

Comment: Are you using a multithreaded runtime library?  VisualStudio for example has two - a single threaded and multi threaded.

Comment: Based on your analysis, is your question really "Why is std::locale not threadsafe?"

Comment: Yes! Is your question really why my question is why?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in libstdc++: std::locale constructor should not require any locking around it. May I suggest you report a bug report to GCC? See [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/)

Comment: @bug report: So far I could not reproduce it without boost. Tried it with a `std::money_get` facet instead. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried stepping into the std::locale ctor and seeing what stuff is done there that might not be thread safe?

Comment: How? I run the code in a parallel for loop with 10^6 iterations - and even then the problem does not always occour.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem in my code... it's really weird (with clang 3.5.0-svn217640-1~exp1 and gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) on ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 1):

I see there is a call to local_time. I am not sure if the underlying code calls localtime or localtime_r. If it calls localtime, then it is not thread safe. I believe that localtime uses a static variable when it returns the result.